# Unable to connect to Twitter API using Spark Streaming

Tags: spark-streaming, twitter-oauth

For the first time, I am using Twitter API for analysis. I am not able to connect to it by using Spark. I am using Scala with SBT and following dependencies:

> "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.5.2",
>   "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "1.5.2",
>   "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-twitter_2.11" % "1.5.2"

I have created the twitter app and got all access tokens. I am getting following error:

```
 PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ

Comment: Already checked. Still not able to get what I have to try :P